# How to view R's source code (pre-parsing)

Tags: r

Embarrassingly basic question.

When wanting to understand R's source code I will often just write its name in R and read through the code.  The downside of this method is that I will get the code with its comment stripped away.

Assuming I use git, and not subversion, what simple solutions do I have to view the source code?

For example, can I download the R's source code through git? (as in with github)

Is there some website with all of the code easily searchable?

Thanks.

Comment: [Suraj Gupta](http://stackoverflow.com/users/356790/sfun28) keeps a copy of the [R releases in his git repo](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source) (note this doesn't include R-devel).

Comment: Why can't you use a SVN web browser to view the code?  Why can you not use SVN to check out the code?

Comment: Dirk, that is what I am asking - what is the "easiest to have" method.  I do not know what an SVN web browser is.  As to using SVN, I would rather use git since this is what I already use for other projects (if possible)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To download the current R-development svn using git-svn (you might need to install git-svn in addition to git):

```
git svn clone https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/
```

To browse R-project source code online, just visit the same site:

```
https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/
```

Or, for the other branches:

```
https://svn.r-project.org/R/
```

To search for, say, `glm()` related code in the R-development source code, I usually try a Google search:

```
glm site:svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/
```

Comment: @TalGalili: I know it works with git-bash. I assume git-gui has the same capability, but I usually use git-bash on Windows.